# Find series of similar elements in a arraylist

Tags: java

I have a arraylist of type integer. The list contains some values.
At some point the list will contain similar values consecutively (3 values).
I need to find the position at which the 3 similar elements appear.

For example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> int_values=new ArrayList<Integer>();
int_values.add(10);
int_values.add(20);
int_values.add(30);
int_values.add(10);
int_values.add(10);
int_values.add(10);
```

As can be seen from position 3 to 5 there are similar values.
So I need to retrieve the position 5.
Also this series of similar elements repeating will occur only once.

I hope I am able to explain the scenario.

Comment: Is this your homework? write the approach is in your mind, you can expect positive result on that.

Comment: array list is not fits to your needs. use map instead of array where key will be `int` and `value`  will quantity of the similar `ints`

Comment: This seems like a fairly simple problem, have you tried solving it? If so, what have you come up with that doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below,

```
public static List<Integer> findConsequtive3(ArrayList<Integer> int_values) {

        Integer[] arrayItems = (Integer[]) int_values.toArray(new Integer[0]);

        List<Integer> consequetive = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < arrayItems.length; i++) {
            if (arrayItems[i - 1] == arrayItems[i]) {
                count++;
                if (count == 3) {
                    consequetive.add(i + 1); // Since array is zero indexed adding 1
                    count = 0; // resetting count
                }
            }
        }
        return consequetive;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> int_values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int_values.add(10);
    int_values.add(20);
    int_values.add(30);
    int_values.add(10);
    int_values.add(10);
    int_values.add(10);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < int_values.size() - 2; i++) {
        if (int_values.get(i) == int_values.get(i + 1))
            if (int_values.get(i + 1) == int_values.get(i + 2))
                System.out.println(i+2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. @Achintya.I was getting stuck if there are 4 or more consecutive similar values

Comment: @Joyson What you want in case of 4 or more consecutive similar values?